# Update a collection in Mongo based on antothe collection with a "join"

Tags: mongodb

I using Mongo version 4.2
I need to update a field in one collection as based on a field from another collection, according to a joining condiiton between the to collection.

In a regualr SQL, the update would be:

```
UPDATE col1, col2
SET col2.entityId = col1.Entity_ID
WHERE col1.id = col2.id
and col2.type='DEVICE';
```

I tried a method offered in one answer, but that does not seem to work, or I did not understand it correctly:

```
db.col1.find().forEach(function (doc1) {
    var doc2 = db.col2.findOne({ id: doc1.id },{type:"DEVICE"});
    if (doc2 != null) {
        doc1.Entity_ID=doc2.entityId;
        db.coll01.save(doc1);
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Tamar

Comment: I couldn't find there any reference to an update based on another collection

Comment: you are right i didnt see the other collection, `$merge`  stage might help in your case

Comment: As @Takis mentioned, it can be done with `$lookup` and [`$merge`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/), but you need MongoDB version 4.4, or to create a new collection with MongoDB version 4.2

Comment: Thanks Nimrod, I do have 4.2. Can ou give an example of how to achieve this using a new collection?